# Hibernate xml configuration database level cascade on delete

Tags: xml, hibernate, postgresql, cascading-deletes

I've got problem with fk constraint, I need to have database level cascade delete, I need to use delete query from outside of application. I looking for some opportunity to do that with xml based hibernate configuration, I can't use annotation driven configuration (with @OnDelete annotation). because of project requirements

is there any possibility to do that with XML configuration, or there exist some solution to run query by hibernate (drop and recreate constraint) after db creation?

here is fragment of my xml configuration

```
<many-to-one name="calss2" class="Class2" fetch="join" cascade="delete">
   <column name="CLASS2"/>
</many-to-one>
```

Answer (score 0):

With te old legacy XML mapping, I think you can only set it at the `one-to-many` side:

```
<bag name="children" table="CHILREN" inverse="true">
    <key column="CHILD_ID" on-delete="cascade"/>
    <one-to-many class="Child"/>
</bag>
```

Otherwise, you need to upgrade your project to use annotations.